# Unit Tests in FastAPI

Tags: pytest, fastapi, sqlmodel

I have a backend app developed with FastAPI, using SQLModel (SQLAlchemy & Pydantic) and connected to a Postgres database.
I have integration tests to test if my endpoints are working fine with a stagging PG DB.
But right now I have to write units tests and I don't know how to proceed to test my endpoints and the functions called in a isolated way.

---

Here is a really simplified version of my project:

The **architecture of my project**: (Consider that there is an __ init__.py file in each folder)

```
app/
├── api/
│   ├── core/
│   │   ├── config.py   #get the env settings and distribute it to the app
│   │   ├── .env
│   ├── crud/
│   │   ├── items.py    #the CRUD functions called by the router
│   ├── db/
│   │   ├── session.py  #the get_session function handling the db engine
│   ├── models/
│   │   ├── items.py    #the SQLModel object def as is in the db
│   ├── routers/
│   │   ├── items.py    #the routing system
│   ├── schemas/
│   │   ├── items.py    #the python object def as it is used in the app
│   ├── main.py         #the main app
├── tests/              #the pytest tests
│   ├── unit_tests/
│   ├── integration_tests/
│   │   ├── test_items.py
```

In the **crud/items.py**:

```
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
from sqlmodel import Session, select
from api.models import Item
from api.schemas import ItemCreate


def get_item(db_session: Session, item_id: int) -> Item:
    query = select(Item).where(Item.id == item_id)
    return db_session.exec(query).first()


def create_new_item(db_session: Session, *, obj_input: ItemCreate) -> Item:
    obj_in_data = jsonable_encoder(obj_input)
    db_obj = Item(**obj_in_data)
    db_session.add(db_obj)
    db_session.commit()
    db_session.refresh(db_obj)
    return db_obj
```

In the **db/session.py**:

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
from sqlmodel import create_engine, Session
from api.core.config import settings

engine: Engine = create_engine(settings.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, pool_pre_ping=True)


def get_session() -> Session:
    with Session(engine) as session:
        yield session
```

In the **models/items.py**:

```
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, Field, MetaData

meta = MetaData(schema="pouetpouet")  # https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/issues/20


class Item(SQLModel, table=True):
    __tablename__ = "cities"
    # __table_args__ = {"schema": "pouetpouet"}
    metadata = meta

    id: int = Field(primary_key=True, default=None)
    city_name: str
```

In the **routers/items.py**:

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, HTTPException
from sqlmodel import Session
from api.crud import get_item, create_new_item
from api.db.session import get_session
from api.models import Item
from api.schemas import ItemRead, ItemCreate

router = APIRouter(prefix="/api/items", tags=["Items"])


@router.get("/{item_id}", response_model=ItemRead)
def read_item(
    *,
    db_session: Session = Depends(get_session),
    item_id: int,
) -> Item:
    item = get_item(db_session=db_session, item_id=item_id)
    if not item:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Item not found")
    return item


@router.post("/", response_model=ItemRead)
def create_item(
    *,
    db_session: Session = Depends(get_session),
    item_input: ItemCreate,
) -> Item:
    item = create_new_item(db_session=db_session, obj_input=item_input)
    return item
```

In the **schemas/items.py**:

```
from typing import Optional
from sqlmodel import SQLModel


class ItemBase(SQLModel):
    city_name: Optional[str] = None


class ItemCreate(ItemBase):
    pass

class ItemRead(ItemBase):
    id: int
    class Config:
        orm_mode: True
```

In the **tests/integration_tests/test_items.py**:

```
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from api.main import app

client = TestClient(app)

def test_create_item() -> None:
    data = {"city_name": "Las Vegas"}
    response = client.post("/api/items/", json=data)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    content = response.json()
    assert content["city_name"] == data["city_name"]
    assert "id" in content
```

The point here is that I feel stuck with the `db_session: Session` argument used in all the functions in the crud/items.py and the routers/items.py because I think it is mandatory to get a valid session of a valid postgres connexion for the tests.

---

ps: not being very experienced in backend development, do not hesitate to bring constructive remarks about my code if you notice something strange. It will be very well received.

Comment: This is typically done using [FastAPI's depencency overrides](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-dependencies/), where you create a new dependency that connects to your test database, and override `get_session` with that.

Comment: @M.O. No, this is not the purpose here ! I'd like to test it in an isolated way ! Without using another DB connexion as explained [in this FastAPI doc](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-database/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comments to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76530308), I think **unit** tests should not deal with databases of *any* kind, but instead mock all the functions interacting with databases.

##### Suggested approach

Here is an example for how I would write a unit test for your CRUD function `create_new_item`.

First a simplified setup for demo purposes:

```py
from sqlmodel import Field, SQLModel, Session


class ItemCreate(SQLModel):
    x: str
    y: float


class Item(ItemCreate, table=True):
    id: int | None = Field(primary_key=True)


def create_new_item(db_session: Session, *, obj_input: ItemCreate) -> Item:
    db_obj = Item.from_orm(obj_input)
    db_session.add(db_obj)
    db_session.commit()
    db_session.refresh(db_obj)
    return db_obj
```

The test case:

```py
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import call, create_autospec

from sqlmodel import Session

# ... import Item, ItemCreate


class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_create_new_item(self) -> None:
        test_item = ItemCreate(x="foo", y=3.14)
        mock_session = create_autospec(Session, instance=True)

        expected_output = Item.from_orm(test_item)
        expected_session_calls = [
            call.add(expected_output),
            call.commit(),
            call.refresh(expected_output),
        ]

        output = create_new_item(mock_session, obj_input=test_item)
        self.assertEqual(expected_output, output)
        self.assertListEqual(expected_session_calls, mock_session.mock_calls)
```

Notice that the test never connects to any database. We *must* assume that the SQLAlchemy functions (and by extension those of SQLModel) work as advertised. Otherwise we should not be using them in the first place. Our unit tests need to ensure that we call those functions correctly.

---

##### Even greater isolation

Technically, the way we are testing this function now, we are still relying on *other code we wrote* to function a certain way, namely the models. This is a grey area in my opinion because we technically did not write any methods for those classes, but rely on existing methods of the base classes.

But you *could* argue that the model definitions themselves should be irrelevant to the `create_new_item` function. In other words, a unit test for it succeeding or failing should not depend on whether our model definitions for `Item` and `ItemCreate` **match** in a way that allows one to be constructed from the other.

So a test with the strictest isolation could look like this:

```py
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, call, create_autospec, patch

from sqlmodel import Session

# ... import Item


class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    @patch.object(Item, "from_orm")
    def test_create_new_item2(self, mock_from_orm: MagicMock) -> None:
        test_item = MagicMock()
        mock_session = create_autospec(Session, instance=True)

        expected_output = mock_from_orm.return_value = object()
        expected_session_calls = [
            call.add(expected_output),
            call.commit(),
            call.refresh(expected_output),
        ]

        output = create_new_item(mock_session, obj_input=test_item)
        self.assertEqual(expected_output, output)
        self.assertListEqual(expected_session_calls, mock_session.mock_calls)
```

---

##### Less isolation: A step towards integration

If you want to have a separate type of test that actually *does* perform database queries to check if the results are as expected, you could inject a different session object bound to a SQLite in-memory database engine.

```py
from unittest import TestCase

from sqlmodel import SQLModel, Session, create_engine, select

# ... import Item, ItemCreate


class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_create_new_item3(self) -> None:
        engine = create_engine("sqlite:///")
        SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine)

        test_item = ItemCreate(x="foo", y=3.14)
        expected_output = Item(**test_item.dict(), id=1)

        with Session(engine) as session:
            output = create_new_item(session, obj_input=test_item)
            self.assertEqual(expected_output, output)
            result = session.exec(select(Item)).all()
            self.assertListEqual([expected_output], result)
```

Of course this will not work, if your models have database-specific settings incompatible with SQLite (such as a Postgres schema).

In that case you have various options as discussed in your previous question. You could for example actually create a separate testing database and write some isolation/cleanup logic around your tests. Then supply an engine connected to that testing database instead.

Or you could try to cleverly monkey-patch your way around those specific settings.

Comment: I think that the suggested approach is the one that match with my needs ! Thanks a lot for your time all those explanations !